# How do I exit out of the Kotlinc command-line compiler

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

So, how do I exit out of the Kotlinc command-line compiler? I entered `kotlinc` on my terminal and played with some kotlin on my Mac and now couldn't figure how to exit. It is like the first time I tried vim. Tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, `exit`, `exit()`, `quit` , `quit()` aaand `:q`, but nothing worked!

I Searched the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) and couldn't find this information. Checked here on SO and I didn't find any previous question. Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can quit by using the command ‘:quit’.

it's in the diagram from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html
[image]

you can type ':help' for more commands available to you.

Comment: Oh, it was right there and I didn't see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[control] + [D] is another option as `:quit`